# Sci-fi show marketed towards teens about a blonde girl living on some kind of space station

Tags: story-identification, tv, space, disney

Years ago, in the middle of the night, I woke up and a strange show I’d never seen before was being aired on Disney. It was about a blonde girl, and she lived on some kind of space station with friends. The title of the show had a 'Z' or something in it. The episodes were also numbered in the title, so the names would look something like “name of the show 4,” and there seemed to be a lot of them, because when I watched the show, it was on 16.

Comment: animated or live action?

Comment: @Will - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 17):

Could this be *[Zenon: Girl of the 21st Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenon:_Girl_of_the_21st_Century_(film))*?

> The year is 2049 and Zenon Kar is a 13-year-old girl who lives with
> her family on an Earth-orbiting space station
>
> [image]

Comment: Contains a z, a blonde girl living on a space station, marketed by Disney, has a number in the title.

Comment: This was a movie with two sequels. OP is asking for a series, with 16+ episodes. Unless OP is mixed up, of course..

Comment: @WolfieSmith - OP only watched a few minute of it, decades ago, while half-asleep.

Comment: Thank you for this post of pure nostalgia. I remember watching this when it first aired as a child

Answer (score 3):

The movie in question could be [Zenon: Z3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenon:_Z3&ved=2ahUKEwiYvqDLuIX4AhX-m44IHYdIC2MQFnoECHcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1BUbzI5WQFcKd-F-2XvX7f) (2004). It's the third of Disney's Zenon movies.

This accounts for your memory of "the episodes being numbered in the title," but not that it was the 16th entry.

Comment: The earlier movie in the series had a higher number in the title. *Zenon: Girl of the **21st** Century*